# JavaFx getselected ItemListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I want to return the object listed in ListView But the problem that the ListView is type of pane : ListView and i create a pane with the object i want

```
@FXML
private ListView<Pane> list;
private ObservableList<Pane> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

The insert of objects Annonce :

```
List<Annonce> lstann = As.listerAnnonce();
    lstann.forEach(a -> {

        Pane p = new Pane();
        p = createPaneAnnonce(a );
        data.add(p);
    });
    list.setItems(data);

    public Pane createPaneAnnonce(Annonce a) {
    ...
    ...
    }
```

is it possible to return the object without change the type of ListView ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking or what you are trying to do. Are you saying you want to return an object of type 'Pane' from a List of type 'Annonce'? If so then you need to show your class hierarchy before being able to say if that is possible or not.

Comment: Why do you create a pane that you never use? The new `Pane` you create when initializing `p` is overwritten just in the next line without being read a single time.

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense to create a `ListView<Pane>` in the first place. The data type for your `ListView` should not be a UI type. What's wrong with using a `ListView<Annonce>`, since that seems to solve your problem?

Comment: every pane represent an annonce that manage all the buttons and textfield needed to an specific annonce that's why i created a pane in the first stage and add it to a listview of panes